# SharePoint Foundation 2013 Setup

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I want to install SharePoint Foundation 2013. I checked many post but its very confusing for me as I'm first time going to install SharePoint.My IT team has given the server access where they have installed ""WINDOWS SERVER 2012 R2.Now I've to Setup SharePoint Foundation but I think before SharePoint foundation I've to install SQL Server Express (as we dont have licence one), IIS...not sure what else.

Can anyone please provide me very simple steps to Install SharePoint Foundation 2013.

Comment: Check the below link it might help http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/440608/SharePoint-Installation-on-Windows-Server

Answer (score 1):

Please check out Akarsh Gupta's link for screenshot and prerequisites. Here is a brief summary of the steps.

1. Have your IT team create a domain user for installation. This user should have your server's local administrator role.
2. Make sure your server have Internet connection.
3. Download the SharePoint 2013 installation media. Run the media with setup.bat. You will see a setup screen.
4. Click install software pre-requisites. It will automatically download from Internet and install.
5. Install SharePoint foundation. When it ask for server type choose "Standalone". It will install SQL Express and install SharePoint on it.
6. Once the installation is completed you will be launched with the Products Configuration Wizard. Choose "create a new SharePoint farm" and use default choice for everything else.

Comment: My IT team has installed "WINDOWS SERVER 2012 R2" and "MS SQL Server". They have given Admin Rights to me. Now I've to install SharePoint Foundation 2013. Here I've doubt on point# 1, 3 & 5
1) I'm not sure about Domain user but yes they have separate server for SharePoint where they have installed SQL server and give Admin ID and password to me to install SP Foundation 2013.
2) Here as per your above point before install pre-requisites I've to run setup.bat?
3) Now SQL Server has already installed so still I can chose "Standalone" or some other option?
Please advice.

Comment: Choose "Complete" instead of "Standalone" for SQL Server install. The install account should have securityadmin and dbcreator SQL Server security roles. You still need to install pre-requisties.

Comment: For first time install the above should be good to go. If you concern security you need to create more accounts for different roles. Please read http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263445(v=office.15).aspx